# Tridion 2011 SP1 : Tridion GUI Javascript error with Translation Manager and Powertools 2011 installed

Tags: javascript, translation, tridion

I recently installed Tridion 2011 SP1 with SDL module Translation Manager enabled.

Everything was working fine. Then I installed the Tridion 2011 Powertools, following the installation procedure.

When trying to reload the GUI (browser cache emptied and modification parameter instanciated for server element in WebRoot\Configuration\System.Config) I'm getting the following Javascript error :

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'getItemType': object is null or undefined
>      Dashboard_v6.1.0.55920.18_.aspx?mode=js, line 528 character 851

And here is the concerned JS line:

> Tridion.TranslationManager.Commands.Save.prototype._isAvailable=function(c,a){var
>      e=c.getItem(0),f=$models.getItem(e),b=f.getItemType(),d=$models.getItem(this.getTmUri ())

The preceding Javascript lines are dealing with other TranslationManager commands, so I suppose it is a kind of TranslationManager commands registration or somehting.

Trying to browse my Tridion publications by selecting any folder/strucutreGroup will also give the same error and the right frame (content frame) will not display any Tridion items but simply display:

> Loading ...

Has anyone already experienced similar issue ?

For now I have no other choice than commenting out the Powertools sections file

> Tridion_Home\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.Config

Thank you,
François

Comment: Do the PowerTools actually work for you? What happens if you comment out Translation Manager instead and try out the Power Tools?

Comment: Yes, the PowerTools are working fine (Count Items, Page Publisher). If I comment out Translation Manager instead, everything is working all fine, included the PowerTools, and no more Javascript errors.

I already opened a ticket @ Tridion Support, but as they do not support the PowerTools they suggested me to post on Stackoverflow.
Now it looks to me the problem is really related to Translation Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Strange thing here is that it refers to Save command which is not intended to be called or used from Dashboard.

I`d suggest to disable JS minification (JScriptMinifier filter in System.config), as it will probably show more correct details.

Another useful thing would be this error call stack.

--

I was not able to reproduce an issue from initial question, but had following error when I installed PT:

> PowerTools is not defined

which appears in
*\PowerTools\Editor\PowerTools\Client\Shared\Scripts\ProgressDialog\ProgressDialog.js where it tries to register *PowerToolsBase* namespace, instead of *PowerTools*.

I`ll be surprised if adding

> Type.registerNamespace("PowerTools");

at the top of the file will fix a problem, as in my case it was breaking entire GUI no matter if TM included or no.

Answer (score 0):

I did check *\PowerTools\Editor\PowerTools\Client\Shared\Scripts\ProgressDialog\ProgressDialog.js, but the line

> Type.registerNamespace("PowerTools");

was already there, so not the problem here.

Also, I disabled the JS minification. Here are the main methods the UI is loading before getting the error:

```
...
PowerTools.Commands.ItemCommenting.prototype.isValidSelection = function (selection) {
//Use the existing Save command from the CME
return $cme.getCommand("Save")._isEnabled(selection);
}

...

/**
* Executes this command on the selection.
* Override this method to implement the actual functionality.
* @param {Tridion.Core.Selection} selection The current selection.
*/
Tridion.TranslationManager.Commands.SendForTranslation.prototype._execute = function SendForTranslation$_execute(selection)
{
    var selectedItems = selection.getItems();
    if (selectedItems.length == 1)
    {
        var job = $models.getItem(selectedItems[0]);

        if (job)
        {
            if (job.isLoaded())
            {
                job.saveAndSend();
            }
            else
            {
                $log.warn("Unable to send an unloaded job?! {0}".format(job.getId()));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $log.warn("Unable to execute save-and-send-for-translation for this selection: {0}".format(selectedItems));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $log.warn("Unable to save-and-send-for-translation multiple items at a time.");
    }
};

...

Tridion.TranslationManager.Commands.Save.prototype._isAvailable = function Save$_isAvailable(selection, pipeline)
{
    var itemUri = selection.getItem(0);
    var item = $models.getItem(itemUri);
    var itemType = item.getItemType();     !!!!!!!!! fails on this line !!!!!! item is null or not an object
    var config = $models.getItem(this.getTmUri());


    if (pipeline)
    {
        pipeline.stop = false;
    }

    if (config && config.hasChanged() && (itemType == $const.ItemType.CATEGORY || itemType == $const.ItemType.FOLDER || itemType == $const.ItemType.STRUCTURE_GROUP || itemType == $const.ItemType.PUBLICATION))
    {
        if (pipeline)
        {
            pipeline.stop = true;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return this.callBase("Tridion.Cme.Command", "_isAvailable", [selection, pipeline]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It`s clear now.

**PowerTools.Commands.ItemCommenting** is used in Dashboard Toolbar.
This command uses **Save** to check its availability.

In the same time TM thinks that "Save" will only be used on an ItemToolbar.

The difference between this toolbars which cause an issue is that Dashboard view could have any-length selection, when Item view will always have selection having one item (currently opened).

Opening empty dashboard selection is not yet made, ItemCommenting tries to check its availability, by calling Save, which calls all its extensions. And so far as selection is empty

> var itemUri = selection.getItem(0);

will return *null*, as well as

> $models.getItem(null)

What you can do, is to remove ItemCommenting extension command as it is done in tridion powertool trunk editor.config.

http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Editor/Configuration/editor.config?spec=svn942&r=903 [592]

Comment: Thank you very much UI Beardcore! It did the trick.
No more JS errors and Powertools seems to work fine now, except that the CountItems always return the same result whatever the folder I select ... but that must be another unrelated problem.